# Show that if $\int_0^x f(y)dy \sim Ax^\alpha$ then $f(x)\sim \alpha Ax^{\alpha -1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

Let $f$ be a real, continuous function defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that $xf(x)$ is increasing for all sufficiently large values of $x$. Show that if

$$\int_0^x f(y)\,dy \sim Ax^\alpha \quad \left(\,x\to \infty\right)$$

for some positive constants $A$ and $\alpha$, then

$$f(x)\sim \alpha Ax^{\alpha -1} \quad \left(\,x\to \infty\right).$$

Clearly, I have to use differentiation somewhere, but I don't know how to manipulate $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\int_0^x f(y)\,dy}{Ax^\alpha}=1$ to get the desired result.

From suggestions given, I know that by L'hospital's rule, it's enough to show that the limit $\lim \frac{f(x)}{\alpha Ax^{\alpha -1}}$ exists, and this limit equals $
\lim \frac{xf(x)}{\alpha Ax^{\alpha}}$. From here, I'll need to use the given assumption that $xf(x)$ is eventually increasing. But how can I show the existence of the limit based on these facts?

I would greatly appreciate any solutions, hints or suggestions.

Comment: Yes everything from calculus is fine.

Comment: It's not an indeterminate limit.

Comment: This is known as a Tauberian theorem, where you get information about a function from an average of the function. It almost always requires some restriction on the growth of the function.

Comment: @martycohen: Do you have a proof in this specific version of Tauberian theorem? I tried some approaches to derive the existence of limit of $f(x)/x^{\alpha - 1}$ from the given hypothesis that $xf(x)$ is increasing, but so far unsuccessful.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with l'Hospitals's rule: essentially, you know that $\frac F G \to A$ and you would like to show that $\frac {F'} {G'} \to A$. Well, l'Hospital goes in the opposite direction: from the fraction with derivatives to the fraction without. Therefore, you want some sort of *converse* to L'Hospital's theorem. Let me say that the naive converse is not true.

Comment: @AlexM.: The link with LHR is obvious. We only need to show that $f'/g'$ tends to a limit. If we show that it tends to a limit then by LHR this limit must be $A$. So we just have to show the existence of limit and not find its value.

Comment: This problem (and its solution) is discussed in de Bruijn's *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis* on pp. 139-140.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ooh, a tauberian theorem with a simple elementary proof, cool.

Assume $x$ is always so large below that $xf(x)$ is increasing. Fix $\delta>0$. It follows that $$\int_x^{(1+\delta)x}f(y)\,dy\sim A((1+\delta)^\alpha-1)x^\alpha.$$In particular, if $x$ is large enough we have $$\int_x^{(1+\delta)x}f(y)\,dy\le(1+\delta)A((1+\delta)^\alpha-1)x^\alpha.$$But $yf(y)$ increasing shows that $$\int_x^{(1+\delta)x}f(y)\,dy\ge\int_x^{(1+\delta)x}\frac{xf(x)}{y}\,dy=xf(x)\log(1+\delta),$$and combining this with the previous inequality shows that if $x$ is large enough then$$\frac{f(x)}{x^{\alpha-1}}
\le\frac{(1+\delta)A((1+\delta)^\alpha-1)}{\log(1+\delta)}.$$Letting $\delta\to0$ now shows that $$\limsup\frac{f(x)}{x^{\alpha-1}}\le\alpha A.$$The inequality $\liminf f(x)/x^{\alpha-1}\ge\alpha A$ is proved similarly, starting with $$\int_{(1-\delta)x}^xf(y)\,dy\sim A(1-(1-\delta)^\alpha)x^\alpha.$$

Comment: @takecare try that

Comment: very nice proof indeed. +1

Answer (score -2):

First, obviously, $Ax^\alpha\to+\infty$

Now, we can see that

$\lim\frac{\int_0^x f(y)dy}{Ax^\alpha}=1$ which means that

$\lim \int_0^x f(y)dy = \lim Ax^\alpha=+\infty$

Now, you can use L'hopital's rule.

Even though we already know the limit is $1$, L'hopital's statement is more than that.

It states that $\lim \frac{f}{g}=\lim\frac{f'}{g'}$ which technically means you get what you want.

Comment: How do we know that $\lim \int_0^x f(y)dy=\infty$? All we can say from what you have is that it's unbounded. There's no information that guarantees the integral must be positive.

Comment: Mate, assume it was a finite $a$, then since the denominator goes to $+\infty$, the limit is $0$.

If it goes to $-\infty$, then the limit is obviously negative.

Thus, by contradiction with both and by elimination, the only possible limit is $+\infty$. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What does that mean? The denominator here is strictly positive, that's first, and your sequence doesn't tend to $1$ (or to anything for all that it matters)

Comment: L'Hoptials does work here. However you need to be a bit careful in justifying it. You have justified that the limit is indetermined, but you also need to show that the limit exists. $\lim \frac{f}{g} = \lim \frac{f'}{g'}$ is only guaranteed if we know that the latter limit exists (and $\pm\infty$ counts as existing in this context). To do this I think you can use $\lim \frac{f(x)}{A\alpha x^{\alpha-1}} = \lim \frac{xf(x)}{A\alpha x^{\alpha}}$ togeather with the fact that $xf(x)$ is increasing.

Comment: Sorry that example was wrong. What I mean is that the limit of the integral may not exist at all. Clearly, as you've said, the limit can't be a finite value, but how do we know that the limit does exist at all?

Comment: Hmm, because the quotient of the limits exists? I mean, since the limit of the denominator exists and that of the quotient does, I believe that of the numerator exists. Not sure though.

Comment: Yes it does. The expression $\int_0^x f(y)dy \sim Ax^{\alpha}$ means that $\int_0^x f(y)dy = Ax^{\alpha} g(x)$ for some function $g$ satisfying $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = 1$. From this it is perhaps easier to see that we have to have $\lim_{x\to\infty} \int_0^x f(y)dy = \infty$

Comment: @Winther, this is mostly your answer lol. :P

Comment: @Winther, Thanks that really explains the infinity part. But how can we show that $\lim \frac{xf(x)}{\alpha Ax^{\alpha}}$ exists?